# Zookeeper 1.4.11 won't install

Tags: ruby, rvm, apache-zookeeper

I'm having a problem with Zookeeper 1.4.11. It's a dependency of my project, and everytime I try to bundle I get:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
 ...
_zookeeper_interest
_zookeeper_process
make[1]: *** [libzookeeper_st.la] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options.
```

When I look for the `mkmf.log`, it doesn't exist anywhere. Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 3):

The problem was the following line in my ~/.bash_profile:

`export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=always'`

It was inject color characters in unexpected places. The way I found this was looking into the libtool generated by the build script inside Zookeeper, and I found some weird color characters.

Comment: Thanks, this saved me, it was my exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

Newer compiler might have problem with warnings treated as errors:

```
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

in order to ignore those warnings use:

```
CFLAGS=-Wno-error=format-overflow gem install zookeeper --version 1.4.11
```